# Getting the capture of a generic object instance in Java

Tags: generics, java-8

Java 8 here. I have the following POJOs:

```
public class Fizz {
    // ctor, getters & setters, etc.
}

public class Buzz {
    // ctor, getters & setters, etc.
}

public class Foobar {
    // ctor, getters & setters, etc.
}

public class Envelope<PAYLOAD_TYPE> {
    private String name;
    private PAYLOAD_TYPE payload;

    // ctor, getters & setters, etc.
}
```

And the following class that processes an `Envelope`:

```
public class Processor {
    public List<Widget> process(final Envelope<?> envelope) {
        if (envelope is an Envelope<Fizz>) {
            // do something 1
        } else if (envelope is an Envelope<Buzz>) {
            // do something 2
        } else if (envelope is an Envelope<Foobar>) {
            // do something 3
        } else {
            // do something 4
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the determination of what the capture of the `envelope` is in the `Processor#process` class is so that I can make my decisions in the if-else-if blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the payload and check it with `instanceof`:

```
if (envelope.getPayload() instanceof Fizz) { ... }
```